# basic question for python decorator mechanism

Tags: python, decorator

I am a new hand for Python. When I learning decorator and class. There are something I totally dont understand

when we take a look an decorator example:

```
class Log_dec(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, args):
        print('do something before function')
        Result=self.func(args)
        print(Result)
        print('do something after function')
@Log_dec
def myFunc(name):
    return 'My Name is %s'%name
myFunc('Haha')
```

Result is:

```
do something before function
My Name is Haha
do something after function
```

If we compare to another example:

```
class Log_dec(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, args):
        print('do something before function')
        Result=self.func(args)
        print(Result)
        print('do something after function')
    def __CallTwice__(self,a_default_variable):
        print('do something different')
        Result_2=self.func(a_default_variable)
        print(Result_2)

@Log_dec
def myFunc(name):
    return 'My Name is %s'%name
myFunc('Haha')
```

Resuls is still:

```
do something before function
My Name is Haha
do something after function
```

It seems when we execute `myFunc('Haha')`, the function `myFunc` goes into `func` in the `__init__` and the string `Haha` goes into `args` in the `__call__`.

My questions is, why the string `Haha` dont goes into `a_defult_variable` in the `__CallTwice__`??? That makes me confusced.

Or let's say, Why the function `myFunc` don't goes into `a_default_variable` in the `__CallTwice__`. Because I think apparently `def __init__(self, func):` has a same format as  `def __CallTwice__(self,a_default_variable):`
Does it?

Comment: Ignore the `@` syntax. What happens is `now = log(now)`. So `now` is now the `wrapper` function. Does that help?

Comment: If  'now' is the 'wrapper', why we use 'return func(*args,**kw)' instead of 'return wrapper(*args,**kw)' ?

Comment: @lululu Infinite recursion, and then the original function `log` will be completely ignored, which is not what a decorator is for.

Comment: The task of `wrapper` is to call `func` (here: `func=now`) with arbitrary arguments and then do something in addition (here: `print` something). If you used `return wrapper(*args,**kw)` at the place of `return func(*args,**kw)` you would have infinite recursion where `wrapper` calls itself for all eternity.

Comment: I assume you have noticed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together/1594484#1594484 ?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for answer. I understand it will have infinite recursion when I do `return wrapper(*args,**kw)` , but I still dont get the point, why the variable x,y goes into the *args.
See the second example, It's the same question, maybe clearly, why the function `myFunc` goes into the `func`  and 'Haha' goes into the '*args'

Comment: @lululu I think you need to explain in a clearer way how it could/should be different. Do you know how starred and double-starred arguments work, e.g. `*args` and `**kwargs`? There are no special rules at work in your examples.

Comment: @timgeb  Thankyou for your suggestion. I changed my Question already. Would you like to give me some help?

Comment: I think you should consume the link by moooeeep and then come back.

Comment: Your `__CallTwice__` method is not called anywhere in your code. Where do you expect it to be executed?

Comment: @timgeb Hallo, from my view `__CallTwice__` has the exactly same format as `__call__`, If the function `myFunc(name)` was executed on `Result=self.func(args)` , It should be also executed on `Result_2=self.func(a_default_variable)` as well. So from my understand, the results should be
 `do something before function
My Name is Haha
do something after function  
do something different 
 My Name is Haha`

Answer (score 3):

This answer just rewrites your example with self-documenting names and without the @-syntax.

```
def create_new_function_from_existing_function(old_function): # def log
    def new_function(*some_positional_arguments, **some_keyword_arguments): # define wrapped function
        print('call %s:' % old_function.__name__)
        return old_function(*some_positional_arguments, **some_keyword_arguments)
    return new_function # return wrapped function

def now(x, y):
    print('2021-9-3 value=', x + y)

now = create_new_function_from_existing_function(now) # @log ...
```